# Xcode device information in milliseconds

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is there any possible way to achieve millisecond precision when using the "Xcode device information" (Xcode > Window > Device)? I need it to run some tests on some iPhone applications? Right now, the time is given in seconds, which is too inaccurate.

If not possible, are there any other programs/consoles that are able to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: added more precise information on where to find the "device information" window.

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean by "xCode device information"? Which method do you use "Right now"?

Comment: xCode device means what ?

Comment: xCode> windows > devices.
Here i select my device and i'm able to see output, but the time stamps are in seconds which isn't precise enough...

Comment: so you want a `NSLog()` function that displays milliseconds?

Comment: I want a console with timestamps in milliseconds rather than in seconds